# AutoHotkey: How to transform a word into a start tag and end tag, e.g. "div" becomes "<div></div>"

Tags: autohotkey

I really like Zen Coding and other features that help to speed up coding, e.g. automatic tags. Especially when using normal text editors on the web, it would be really helpful to imitate this behavior with AutoHotkey:

Enter `div`, hit `CTRL+E` and it becomes `<div></div>`, putting the cursor | in the middle `<div>|</div>`.

Furthermore, this should work for every word, no matter what length.

E.g. `p` → CTRL+E → `<p></p>`

`span` → CTRL+E → `<span></span>`

Comment: With a Space instead of Ctrl-E you can use [Hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm): `:O:div::<div></div>{left 6}`

Comment: As said, I would like arbitrary words. Even a `whatsoever` + `CTRL+E` should turn into `<whatsoever></whatsoever>`

Comment: Okay, now the goal is clear, so what's your best attempt at solving this? Have you tried adapting similar existing solutions if any? Currently the question looks like a do-it-for-me request.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it because I am new to AHK. And yes, I was searching a lot before asking here. I know for instance how to trigger CTRL+E but this is not enough to get the issue solved.

Comment: I would use editor's built-in macro language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
^e::
    Send, ^+{left}^c<^v></^v>
    StringLen, x, clipboard
    x := x+3
    Send, {left %x%}
return
```

And figure out from Help how and why it works.

Comment: +1 for really being creative. You might want to empty the clipboard and add `ClipWait` right after `^c`, before pasting or reading the clipboard contents.

Comment: @MCL - Agreed.  I have a more sophisticated version that uses `ClipWait` and also saves the current clipboard at the start and restores it at the end.  I also check to see if there is already a space, tab or terminal punctuation before and after the word do be converted and deal with those appropriately (I am often using Dragon NaturallySpeaking to dictate, or have autocomplete and hotstrings which sometimes add extra leading or trailing spaces).  I stripped my answer down for OP because I wanted to encourage additional learning by doing (and OP can ask for add'l guidance after digesting).